# on the "local" toolchain in linux

Tags: linux, bash, path

long time lurker first time poster.

I've looked everywhere and I'm sure it's easily found but I couldn't properly word the search.

I working on some coding exercises from a textbook and I've got all my work in directories with the following hierarchy:

```
        r00t
       /    \
  tools      code
                 \
                  chapts
```

In the tools directory are a couple scripts to make my life easier. What I want, and the reason I'm posting, is to be able to call the scripts in r00t/tools wherever I am, as long as I'm inside r00t. I know I could just add them to the global PATH but that seems lazy and I don't want my PATH to balloon any more (is this even sensible?).

So, can I add scripts or programs to the "local PATH" inside the dir somehow?

Comment: There's nothing built into any shell I know of that will enable this functionality. The `git` somewhat accomplishes this by searching up the directory hierarchy, looking for a `.git` directory. Your best option is probably just to add thextra directory to your PATH.

Comment: :'(  That's what I was beginning to think myself. I guess there's no reason your $PATH var can't get super huge, just that it's unwieldy to edit. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848832/directory-based-environment-variable-scope-how-to-implement) towards the `ondir` ([link](http://swapoff.org/ondir.html)) program letting you execute scripts upon entering or leaving directories.

With that you could dynamically change your path variable. I must however admit to never have used the program nor to be informed about its development status.

Alternatively you could replace your `cd` command with a script checking `pwd` versus your r00t directory and updating `$PATH` based on the outcome. of course your `cd` will be slowed down but probably not even noticeably.

an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

#alternative cd

cd $*

#check for r00t directory
if [ "$( pwd | grep -o 'r00t')" == "r00t" ] ; then
  #check path variable:
  if [ "$(echo $PATH | grep -o 'r00t')" != "r00t" ] ; then
        export PATH=$PATH:/DIR/r00t/bin
  fi
else
  #remove r00t from PATH when not in r00t
  if [ "$(echo $PATH | grep -o 'r00t')" == "r00t" ] ; then
        export PATH=$( echo $PATH | sed 's~:/DIR/r00t/bin~~' )
  fi
fi
```

note that now you'll have to intoduce the `alias` as follows:

```
alias cd='. ./path/to/script/alternative_cd.sh'
```

as the exported PATH needs to be sourced in order to work for your current shell (if using `bash alternative_cd.sh`, you'd only get the new PATH for the subshell the script is run in)

I tested it and it seemed to be working. Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to handle this is to put an [rc file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_file) in the root directory of each of your project directory trees. In this case, `r00t`. Call the file `r00trc` or make your own naming convention.

The rc file should include an identifying change to the command line prompt in order to remind you constantly what environment the shell is using, and a re-assignment of the `PATH` variable to suite the needs of the project, and any other project-specific environment variables, aliases or color setting that you need.

From your default login environment, spawn a sub-shell by running 'bash' either before or after or without changing the current working directory to `r00t` and then source the `r00trc` file. This provides you with a Bash shell with the project environment and an identifying prompt. Use `exit` to exit the sub-shell and return to your default environment.

Avoid the temptation to collect your project rc files in your home directory or anywhere other than the root of the project directories so that they do not get lost when you tar up a project and archive it or send it to a colleague.

Comment: Really great advice here, just want to say this has served me well over time!